# "No qualifying bean of type 'com.genecab.bank.AccountRepository' available" when converting to spring-data-jpa from in-memory database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I'm almost there on persisting my H2 database using JPA in the application for the first time, but I'm running into the error message `No qualifying bean of type 'com.genecab.bank.AccountRepository' available`. The application works in memory, but when spring-data-jpa is added to the build.gradle it does not find this bean.

The command I ran to reproduce this was as follows:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local build\libs\bank-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here are more details on the failure from the Spring log:

```
2023-12-02T09:37:16.805-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1944 ms
2023-12-02T09:37:16.848-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-12-02T09:37:17.173-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/bank user=BANK-USER
2023-12-02T09:37:17.178-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-12-02T09:37:17.197-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/bank'
2023-12-02T09:37:17.400-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 9.5.1 by Redgate
2023-12-02T09:37:17.401-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : See what's new here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#9.5.1
2023-12-02T09:37:17.408-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    :
2023-12-02T09:37:17.431-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.database.base.BaseDatabaseType   : Database: jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/bank (H2 2.1)
2023-12-02T09:37:17.514-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.024s)
2023-12-02T09:37:17.526-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "PUBLIC": 2
2023-12-02T09:37:17.528-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema "PUBLIC" is up to date. No migration necessary.
2023-12-02T09:37:17.664-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-12-02T09:37:17.757-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-12-02T09:37:18.269-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-12-02T09:37:18.672-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-12-02T09:37:18.690-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-12-02T09:37:18.708-05:00  WARN 24540 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/biz/IdeaProjects/genecab-bank/build/libs/bank-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/genecab/bank/AccountController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.genecab.bank.AccountRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2023-12-02T09:37:18.708-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-12-02T09:37:18.719-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-12-02T09:37:18.762-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-12-02T09:37:18.766-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-12-02T09:37:18.788-05:00  INFO 24540 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-12-02T09:37:18.819-05:00 ERROR 24540 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.genecab.bank.AccountController required a bean of type 'com.genecab.bank.AccountRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.genecab.bank.AccountRepository' in your configuration.
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.genecab'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

My unit tests were passing when I commented out the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa line like this:

```
    // implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
```

...and I can also run `.gradlew bootRun` successfully when that is commented out. However, when I put it in, the unit tests fail with errors like the following:

```
BankApplicationTests > shouldCreateANewJournalEntry() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:798
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException at DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1824
```

So it seems similar to the problem in the original log when trying to run bootRun with the local configuration.

Here is my application-local.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/bank
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=bank-user
spring.datasource.password=&zsD9*PfZ0sgfNbW
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.flyway.user=bank-user
spring.flyway.password=&zsD9*PfZ0sgfNbW
spring.flyway.url=jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/bank
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
spring.flyway.enabled=true

# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

And my AccountRepository.java:

```
package com.genecab.bank;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<Account, Long> {
    Account findByIdAndOwner(Long id, String owner);
    Page<Account> findByOwner(String owner, PageRequest amount);

    Optional<Account> findById(Long accountId);
}
```

The full source code is available at [this Github source code link](https://github.com/mifran/bank-troubleshooting/tree/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT) if that makes it easier.

I also tried adding @EnableJpaRepositories but this didn't work.

I wrestled for some time with the schema initialization and ultimately implemented flyway, which shows in the log that the schema initialization is successful, so I know the underlying tables and data are being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are using record as an Entity for your JPA

```
public record Account(@Id Long id, String name, String type, String owner {

}
```

> Entities are handled by the JPA provider. JPA providers are
> responsible for creating the database tables, mapping the entities to
> the tables, and persisting the entities to the database. In popular
> JPA providers like Hibernate, entities are created and managed using
> proxies.
>
> Proxies are classes that are generated at runtime and extend the
> entity class. These proxies rely on the entity class to have a no-args
> constructor and setters. Since records don’t have these, they can’t be
> used as entities.

For now, you can do the following, keep in mind that @Table is optional

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String owner;

    // JPA requires a no argument constructor
    protected Account() {}

    public Account(Long id, String name, String type, String owner) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    // Getters and setters (if not using Lombok)
    // ...
}
```

Based on the code you've shared BankApplication and AccountRepository are in the same package (com.genecab.bank), component scanning should automatically pick up AccountRepository as a Spring Bean.
Try to fix Account as I described and explicitly specify the following in BankApplication

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.genecab.bank")
```

I also would recommend you to remove unnecessary dependency

```
implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jdbc'
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I performed the actions you recommended and now I'm getting the error `Entity 'com.genecab.bank.Account' has no identifier (every '@Entity' class must declare or inherit at least one '@Id' or '@EmbeddedId' property)`. The new source code is at https://github.com/mifran/bank-troubleshooting/tree/patch1 . Any ideas on this next error? @ruslan-zinovyev

Comment: Please add this
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

Comment: Fixed! I had to use `@jakarta.persistence.Id`

Comment: glad to hear it

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for your help! It's all working now.

Comment: you are very welcome